# Translating performance run from autocannon to locust

Tags: performance, locust

I need to translate autocannon performance test into locust python code and reach the same requests per second criteria > 3000

this is the autocannon command:

```
AUTOCANNON="taskset -c 8-15 /opt/autocannon-tests/node_modules/.bin/autocannon --amount 100000 --connections 30 --bailout 5 --json"

$AUTOCANNON $URL/applications -m PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization=$AUTHORIZATION_HEADER" -b '{"name":"test"}'
```

**I managed to reach number of requests per second > 3000**

I wrote a python code

```
class _PerformanceTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SequentialTaskSet.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.username = 'admin'
        self.password = 'admin'
        self.token = None
        self.identifier = time.time()
        self.error = None
        self.as3_user_id = None
        self.non_admin_user_token = None
        self.as3_user_token = None
        self.system_id = None
        self.open_api_retrieve_count = 0
        self.declare_id = None
        self.network_id = None
        self.irule_app = None
        self.irule_network_id = None
        self.application_editor_user = None

    def on_start(self):
        self.login()

    def _log(self, fmt, *args):
        print('[%s] %s' % (self.identifier, fmt % args))

    def _request(self, method, path, non_admin_user_token=False, headers=None, **kwargs):
        self._log('[%s]%s', method, path)
        self._log('%s', repr(kwargs))
        if not headers:
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        if self.token:
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer %s' % self.token
        if non_admin_user_token:
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer %s' % self.non_admin_user_token
        resp = self.client.request(method, path, headers=headers, **kwargs)
        self._log('resp status code: %s', resp.status_code)
        self._log('resp content: %s', resp.text)
        assert resp.status_code in (200, 201, 204, 202)
        if (re.search('^[\[\{]', resp.text)):
            return resp.json()
        return resp.text

    def login(self):
        self._log('login')
        resp = self._request(
            method='GET',
            path='/login',
            auth=(self.username, self.password),
        )
        self.token = resp['token']
        self._log('token is: %s', self.token)

 @task
    def run_performance(self):
        self._log('PUT request to $URL/applications with auth. header.')
        resp = self._request(
            method='PUT',
            path='/applications',
            json={
                "name":"test",
            }
        )

        self._log('response is: %s', resp)



class PerformanceTask(FastHttpUser):
    tasks = [_PerformanceTask]
```

Note: I am using FastHttpUser + locust-plugins installed
But I can't reach the same result.
The ways I run this performance.py script

```
locust --locustfile performance.py --host https://localhost:5443/api/v1 --headless -u 30 -i 100000
```

and also distributed:

```
locust --locustfile performance.py --host https://localhost:5443/api/v1 --headless -u 30 -i 10000 --master --expect-workers=8

and start workers like 
locust --locustfile performance.py --worker --master-host=127.0.0.1 -i 10000 &
```

anyway - I get table of results and the speed is much lower no matter how I run :

req/s failures/s

---

224.49    0.00

I hope you have ideas

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with autocannon so I'm not entirely sure, but a quick look through the documentation says that the `--connections` doesn't seem like it translates to Locust's `--users`/`-u`. It says it's "The number of concurrent connections to use." To get something similar to that, I believe you'd have to set up a FastHttpSession and specify `concurrency` there. Something like:

```
fast_http_session = FastHttpSession(environment=env, base_url="https://localhost:5443/api/v1", user=None, concurrency=30)
```

You'll need to get the environment from Locust when it runs to pass it into there, and may or may not want to specify your actual user (which you can pass as `self` if you put this in your user class).

But that should get you the number of concurrent connections to use, and then you'd want to crank up the number of users you spawn. As you make your calls using the session you created, the users will reuse the 30 open connections, it will just be up to you to discover how many users you need to spawn to "saturate" the connections like autocannon claims to do and/or how many the machine you run it on can handle.